# Breeze issues with WebApi 2 ODataConventionModelBuilder metadata

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently working on an OData Web API 2 service using EF6 with a code first approach.

The breeze documentation suggests the use of the EdmBuilder over the ODataConventionModelBuilder for multiple reasons (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata-server). I had a couple of questions over this-:

1) The ODataConventionModelBuilder appears to not generate the 'ReferentialConstraint' tag thereby having an impact on $select after $expand on using the breeze js client. But strangely, the same appears to work when directly typed into the browser (using $expand & $select), Is there any work around to using the ODataConventionModelBuilder? Are all the issues stated in the link still applicable?

2) We opted for a pure OData service to make our API accessible for varied OData consumers, we  wish to keep our services generic without any breeze flavor to it. Will the addition of the EdmBuilder make the service breeze specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered Microsoft's ODataConventionModelBuilder does NOT provide referential constraints.  So far, using the EdmBuilder is the only workaround.  Using the EdmBuilder does not make the service breeze specific, because there is no breeze specific code there. (The code for EdmBuilder was actually provided by a Microsoft engineer.)  However, using the EdmBuilder does preclude you from using the rest of the ODataConventionModelBuilder functionality, which is annoying.

What we are considering, is allowing the OData metadata delivered from the server to be modified/updated via series of api calls where you would declare the relational constraints ***directly on the client***.  You would then be using the ODataConventionModel builder instead of the EdmBuilder and using the 'new' api to 'reset' the constraints.  This is obviously not as good as retrieving the data from the server, but until MS fixes the ODataConventionModelBuilder this may be our best bet.

Would this be of value in your scenario?

Also, please contact MS and let them know of your frustration. :)

Comment: Jay, using the EdmBuilder sounds to be a better option as of now. Does the EdmBuilder also help resolve the other problems stated in your website -i.e transactions, batch save and save order.

Comment: Jay, in addition to the above question - strangely using just plain datajs I am able to make a query like /odata/Categories(1)?$expand=Products&$select=Products to a service making use of the ODataConventionModelBuilder. 

The same query returns a 'property not found error' through breeze. Now I am confused :(

Comment: We aren't saying that Web API OData can't return a graph of related data. We're saying it doesn't supply the ref info (FKs) Breeze needs to **maintain the relationship**. Using straight data.js you can issue expand queries and receive the related data nested within the `Category` results. However, **these returned data are NOT entities** and the `Category.Products` array would not be maintained (e.g., subsequent adds or removes) by any apparatus on the client ... as you would expect if it were managed by Breeze.

Comment: The model builder - whether `ODataConventionModelBuilder` or `EdmBuilder` - describes the model to OData and is the source of metadata for the client. It has nothing to do with how OData processes batch save requests. That is handled by the `batchHandler`. The only `batchHandler` shipped today is the `DefaultODataBatchHandler` ... which is lacking in all the ways we describe in the documentation. I'm afraid the solution to these issues will take the form of a different `batchHandler` written by MS or someone else OR perhaps a completely different Web API OData pipeline. We can hope :-)

Comment: Based on the comments, we have decided to go in with the EdmBuilder as using it should help us use the features Breeze provides. +1 for the super quick response. 

Hopefully MS does come out with a rectified version of the ODataConventionModelBuilder soon, fingers crossed :)